# Sum of range(1,n,2) values using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to translate a loop to a recursive algorithm. Fairly simple, I've just hadn't been able to make it ignore the n value when summing up the values, like range does.

This is the iterative function:

```py
def function(n):
    total=0
    for i in range(1,n,2):
        total += i
    print(total)

function(5) # Output: 4
```

This is the recursive I've tried:

```
def function1(n):
    if n==1:
        return n
    else:
        return n+function1(n-2)
function(5) # Output: 9
```

So `function1` does sum the `n` when it should be ignored. Cause `range()` does not include the stop number.

Then, I tried:

```
def f1(n):
    def f_recursive(n):
        if n==1 or n==2:
            return 1
        elif n==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return n + f_recursive(n - 2)

    return f_recursive(n) - n 

print(f1(5)) # Output: 4 Yeiii!!
```

But then I realised, that only works for odd numbers. Not for even. If `f1(6)` then you get `4` when it should be `9`, because it ends up being 11-6= 9.

So silly me I tried:

```
def f1(n):
    def f_recursive(n):
        if n==1 or n==2:
            return 1
        elif n==0:
            return 0
        elif n%2 == 0:
            return n + f_recursive(n - 3)

        elif n%2 == 1:
            return n + f_recursive(n - 2)

    return f_recursive(n) - n 

print(f1(6))
```

Which of course also did not work. Am I not understanding recursion properly here?

Comment: Does it need to be recursion? you could just do `sum(range(1,n,2))`

Comment: @Sayse Hi, yeah. It's kind of a requirement. Can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is excluding the upper bound. If the upper bound is your only parameter `n`, you have to know when it's the first call, and when it's an intermediate (recursive) call. Alternatively, if inner functions are okay, you could instead just count from 1 up until you hit `n`:

```
def function1(n):
    def inner(i):
        return 0 if i >= n else i + inner(i + 2)
    return inner(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your recursion is that you're returning `n` rather than the value in the range (list) that you're currently on, this poses a problem since `n` is not inclusive within the range and should not be added to the final total

Ideally you need to reverse the logic and traverse it the same way your range does

```
def func(start,end, step):
    if(start >= end):
        return 0

    return start + func(start + step, end, step)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to compute the sum of all odd integers from 1 up to, but not including, n.

This leaves 2 possibilities:

1. If `n` is <= 1, there are no numbers to sum, so the sum is 0.
2. The highest number that *might* be included in the list is `n-1`, but only if it is odd.  Either way, the rest of the sum is "*the sum of all odd integers from 1 up to, but not including, n-1*" (sound familiar?)

This translates to:

```
def f1(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    else:
        isOdd = (n-1)%2==1
        return f1(n-1) + (n-1 if isOdd else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to recognize the three types of ranges you might be adding up.

1. `range(1, n, 2)` where `n <= 1`: The empty range, so the sum is 0
2. `range(1, n, 2)` where `n > 1` and `n` is even: the range is 1, ..., n-1. (E.g. `range(1, 6, 2) == [1, 3, 5]`)
3. `range(1, n, 2)` where `n > 1` and `n` is odd: the range is 1, ..., n-2 (E.g., `range(1, 5, 2) == [1, 3]`

Translating this to code is straightforward:

```
def f_recursive1(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return n - 1 + f_recursive1(n-2)
    else:  # n odd
        return n - 2 + f_recursive1(n-2)
```

However, this does more work than is strictly necessary, since subtracting 2 from `n` will never change its parity; you don't need to check `n` is even or odd in *every* recursive call.

```
def f_recursive2(n):
    def f_helper(x):
        if x <= 0:
            return 0
        return x + f_helper(x-2)

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return f_helper(n-1)
    else:
        return f_helper(n-2)
```

Comment: I think it's fixed now. The refactored one (now renamed `f_recursive2`) used the wrong base case in `f_helper`. (`range(1,n,2)` generates numbers up to, but not including, `n`, while `f_helper(n)` computes the sum of `range(1, n+1, 2)`).

Answer (score 0):

If we are allowed multiplication and division, I hope you realise that this particular task does not require more than just a base case.

Python code:

```
def f(n):
  total=0
  for i in range(1,n,2):
    total += i
  return total

def g(n):
  half = n // 2
  return half * half

for n in xrange(100):
  print f(n), g(n)
```

Since

```
         *
       * * *
     * * * * *
   * * * * * * *
```

can be seen as nested, folded rows. Here are the top two folded rows:

```
         *
       * * *
     * *   * *
   * *       * *
```

Let's rotate counterclockwise 45 degrees

```
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
   *  *
   *  *
```

and add the other two folded rows,

```
       *
     *   *

   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *
```

and

```
       *
```

to get

```
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
   *  *  *  *
```

the area of a square.